Function templates and class templates with non-type template parameters differ when instantiated with an empty parameter pack of types
I have the following program with a function template and a class template, both of which have a non-type template parameter. If I try to pass an empty parameter pack of types to the class template, it fails, but for the function template it works.
template<int = 42>
struct Class {};

template <int = 42>
void Function() {}

template<typename... Args>
void test() {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == 0);
    Class<Args...>{};                     // error
    Function<Args...>();                  // ok
}

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Eze186587
The error from GCC for line Class<Args...>{}; is:
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<int <anonymous> > struct Class'
   11 |     Class<Args...>{};
      |                  ^
note:   expected a constant of type 'int', got 'Args'
note: so any instantiation with a non-empty parameter pack would be ill-formed

Why is Class<Args...>{} rejected but Function<Args...>() accepted?
Why do function templates and class templates differ in this way?

Because Args is empty.  T becomes float, Args is empty, and there is no Foo<> with an empty list, where as there is a another<> with an empty list.

caveat Foo<Args...>{}; is not same as Foo<>{};. gotta do if constexpr or SFINAE-something

why would another<Args...>(); fail? We can only explain where your misunderstanding is when you tell us your line of reasoning

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Foo and another are both templated on defaultable integers. Yet Foo rejects Foo<Args...> while another accepts another<Args...>. Why do function template default template parameters differ from class template default template parameters?

@RaymonChen my fault, misread the code. Its rather obvious what the expecations are

Notice that static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == 0); make the function IFNDR, see why-template-with-only-valid-empty-variadic-pack-ill-formed

@cigien Your edit invalidates all comments and the answer. Please undo; the streamlined text is not worth the confusion that it causes.

@j6t The edits don't invalidate the answer (and couldn't, given the answer was posted an hour after the edits). Yes, the comments are now a little confusing, but invalidating comments that are asking for clarification (or arise from a misunderstanding) is a good thing. Comments that are providing answers should be made into answers, at which point they can use the edited version of the question. I don't see any point in converting the edits to a less clear version, just to preserve some comments. For people who really want to understand the comments, they can look at the edit history.

@Jarod42 Actually we could remove the static_assert line. Situation is that there is another function will call test() like:
template <int a, int b, auto... Args>
void foo() {
    // ...
    test<Args...>();
    // ...
}


Even without static_assert, to be valid Class<Args...>{} might be valid only with empty pack, so the same reason of IFNDR.

Your program is ill-formed NDR:
https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#general-6.5

The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if

[..]


every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack, or


Diagnose that is just a Quality of Implementation.

Thanks. Could you please explain Diagnose that is just a Quality of Implementation.? Is there a way to by-pass the ill-form?

Why wouldn't the Foo<Args...>(); fail?

"Could you please explain", as the program is IFNDR (No Diagnostic Required), any diagnostic is up to compiler if any. I don't know why they provide diagnostic for class and not for function (maybe because of overload handling which make is more difficult). Notice that they might provide other reason for the error.

"Is there a way to by-pass the ill-form?" I'm not sure how to change the code in a way which is valid, but still expose your issue. void test() { Class<>{}; Function<>();} would be ok...

Actually I can't remove Args... because Args could not be an empty pack, it could override the default template paramter.

But how Foo<Value> would be replaced by Foo<Types...> with a non-empty pack?

Thanks for reply. I mean that Class<>() is actually OK. But what if we want to change the default value of Class's struct template parameter in Args...? If Args... is 5, then I can change the default template parameter of Class from 42 to 5. So I have to pass the Args... like Class<Args...>(), which will have error like the description said.

But Args... are types, maybe you want template<int... Ns> void test() instead Demo.

thanks for your remind, using auto... will solve my case. Thank you!

For the comilation error, I bypassed it with replace
template<typename... Args>

with
template<auto... Args>

Which will let compiler deduce non-typed template parameters pack. That will solve my problem.
Please check:
https://godbolt.org/z/fT9qEfsxT
And what @Jarod42 said is right.
